# Get 30 days back date along with time

Tags: php, date, datetime, datetime-format

I want to calculate EXACT past 30 days time period in php from now (for example 30 aug 14 23:06) to 30 days back (for example 1 aug 14 23:06). I wrote this where current datetime goes in $d1 and past 30 days datetime goes in $d2 but somehow i am not getting correct results. Any idea?

```
$url=$row["url"];
$pageid=getPageID($url);
$date=date('y-m-d g:i');
$d1=strtotime($date);
$d2=date(strtotime('today - 30 days'));
```

Thanks

Comment: What results are you getting?

Comment: Are you using MySQL to get your records?

Comment: `strtotime('-30 days')` should suffice.

Comment: YOu can simplify `$date=date('y-m-d g:i');
$d1=strtotime($date);` to `$date = time();`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The problem is likely caused by the malformed `date()` call. The first argument passed to `date()` should be the format (as shown in the [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)) and the second should be an optional timestamp.

Try this:

```
$d2 = date('c', strtotime('-30 days'));
```

[**PHPFiddle**](https://eval.in/198645)

---

As a short aside, the whole snippet can be simplified as follows:

```
$url = $row["url"];
$pageid = getPageID($url);
$date = date('y-m-d g:i');
$d1 = time();
$d2 = date('y-m-d g:i', strtotime('-30 days'));
```

Comment: Thanks... $d2 = date('y-m-d g:i', strtotime('-30 days')); this is what i was looking for but goofing up in syntax.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use the `DateTime` class's `sub()` method together with an `DateInterval`:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$back = $now->sub(DateInterval::createFromDateString('30 days'));
echo $back->format('y-m-d g:i');
```

Answer (score 5):

if you would like to get out put as 2014-08-01 then try the below code. thanks

```
$date = '2014-08-30 23:06';
$new_date = date('Y-m-d G:i', strtotime($date.' - 29 days'));
echo "30 days back is " . $new_date;
```

Answer (score 4):

Very simple two lines of code

`$date = new DateTime();
echo $date->modify('-30 day')->format('y-m-d g:i');`

Answer (score 2):

From your brief description and example given, I believe that you want the date to be 30 days back and time to be the same as of now. The below code will serve this purpose. Thanks.

```
<?php
$date=date('y-m-d g:i');
$time=date('g:i');
echo "Todays date:" . $date. "<br>";
$d2 = date('y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days'));
echo "30 days back:" . $d2 . ' ' .$time;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Try:
echo date("Y-m-d h:i:s",strtotime('-30 days'));
```

For more detail [click](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) here

Answer (score 1):

I know you said with PHP, however, I can't imagine not getting the records from a DB.  If you want to do so from the DB,use:

```
$sql='SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE  date > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 30 DAY';
$pdo->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple one lines of code:

```
echo (new DateTime())->modify('-30 day')->format('y-m-d g:i');
```

> In the example below, it makes no sense if the variable *$date* is not
>   used anywhere else!

```
$date = new DateTime();
echo $date->modify('-30 day')->format('y-m-d g:i');
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample answer is
$dateBack30Days=date('Y-m-d g:i', strtotime('-30 days'));