# changing my SQL Timestamp into a d-m-Y in php

Tags: php, timestamp, strtotime

In my database I use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP to keep track of the registration dates for my new users.
Now I wish to generate a list of users who signed up in the past 7 or 30 days.
I figured it would be as simple as explained in this topic;
[Get 30 days back date along with time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26044844/get-30-days-back-date-along-with-time)

But my current code generates an unexpected output.

```
                for($i = 0; $i < $userlenght; $i++){
                    $comparedate = strtotime(date('Y-m-d', $user[$i]["date"]));
                    echo $comparedate . "<br/>";
                    if($user[$i]["date"] > $last){
                        //do stuff here with the users who match.
                    }
                }
```

This displays the $comparedate value as "-3600" and I have no idea why.

Can anyone provide some insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Timestamp is returned formatted as a string, so you need to instruct PHP to read the string as a date formatted value. To do so you need to use `strtotime()`.

Try the following:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $userlenght; $i++){
       $comparedate = strtotime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($user[$i]["date"])));
       echo $comparedate . "<br/>";
       if($user[$i]["date"] > $last){
             //do stuff here with the users who match.
       }
}
```

Comment: When I filter it through two "strtotime" functions, it just churns out the long list of numbers. `$comparedate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($user[$i]["date"]));` gave me the nicely formatted date.
However, without your comment I wouldnt have figured that out, thanks Alberto!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `$user[$i]['date']` is a MySQL Timestamp which looks like `2018-09-14 11:09:10`, and is not a valid input to `date`. You can just remove the call to `date` and your code should work fine:

```
$comparedate = strtotime($user[$i]["date"]);
```

Comment: Ah see, nothing like that was mentioned in the other topics I could find, but I figured the problem was laying there somewhere.
Thank you Nick!